FLTK library Link Error 2019 when compiling GMSH with GUI with (unresolved external symbol "main")
When trying to compile GMSH (https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/), I face this error:

fltkd.lib(fl_call_main.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
symbol main referenced in function WinMain [\gmsh.vcxproj] \gmsh.exe:
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [\gmsh.vcxproj]

The FLTK library is compiled directly from its repository (https://github.com/fltk/fltk/) without errors.
The compilations of both repositories are performed by MSVC in Windows.
I think the linker can't resolve the call to "main" in "fl_call_main.c".
Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?
OS: Windows 11
Compiler: MSVC (VS 2022)

Sometimes libraries or frameworks have configuration settings that enable using int main() in a windows application instead of using WinMain(). I have used fltk in the past but it was too long ago.

After reading some documentation it appears that FLTK does do what I thought in the above comment. My advice is to look at the individual project that has this error. Does it have an int main() function?

Yes you can see it here: https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/blob/master/src/common/Main.cpp#L42

I think directives "#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(CYGWIN)" are forcing wmain. So int main may not be in the final compilation. Can you give me some clue how to fix this?

I expect to fix the error you could comment out all lines from 9 to 40 + 45 so that just int main() {} is defined and no int wmain(){}

You are right changing #if defined(WIN32) && !defined(CYGWIN) to #if 0 so main () would compile or renaming wmain to main both work. I wonder if there are any side effect though.

I assume the use of wmain requires a new version of FLTK. The side effects is if you run your program you can only use ASCII characters in the command line arguments.

FLTK provides a standard Windows WinMain() entry point in fl_call_main.c, as you (@Saeid) found out, and this entry point eventually calls main(). In FLTK 1.4 (Git) "wide arguments" (i.e. Unicode characters outside the ASCII range) are converted inside this function to the appropriate UTF-8 encoding, which is exactly what the wmain() function of Gmsh would do. I'm not sure whether FLTK 1.3 is up-to-date with this conversion but you wrote that you compiled FLTK from git which is 1.4 by default.
There should be no side effects if you let FLTK do the conversion job in its fl_call_main.c module (i.e. use #if 0 as you wrote in a comment) or if you don't use "Wide Character" arguments on the commandline. Note that under current Windows versions all characters on the commandline that are not in the ASCII character set (Unicode codepoints 0x00 to 0x7F), e.g. filenames, are represented by Windows Wide Characters and need this conversion.
Note also that fl_call_main.c can only be used in static (and maybe in debug) builds (not sure about the latter).
So far the details from the FLTK side. I can't help with Gmsh specific stuff though, for instance why and how wmain() would be compiled and called.

I have solved the unresolved reference problem just by a change the build subsystem from windows to console. VS2022, Windows 10. See issue #1727 in gmsh forum.

This way you won't compile the GUI.

GUI appears with additional console window. Not elegant but allows to concentrate on meshing algorithms and debugging.
